# How to capture YugabyteDB changes to kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, cdc, yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

If I want to capture all the DB updates and send them to a Kafka topic, is there a solution you may suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Yugabyte Source Connector for Kafka](https://github.com/yugabyte/yb-kafka-sink) for both YCQL & YSQL apis. This is based on [JDBC Source connector](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-jdbc/current/source-connector/index.html) that does `select *` to get the data.

Comment: The [description](https://github.com/yugabyte/yb-kafka-sink/tree/798e28d8a1882825bdb7ac4f3d116d25b6e8f1f3) of the YugabyteDB Apache Kafka Connector repo says “An Apache Kafka sink for transferring events/messages from Kafka topics to YugabyteDB. It supports both CQL as well as JDBC Sink”. So this does not seem answer the question because the question is asking how to write YugabyteDB CDC to Kafka instead of how to transfer Kafka topics to YugabyteDB.

Comment: @HongboMiao The same jar has Sink as well as the Source connector. However, the source connector is based on JDBCSource connector that 'queries tables to get the data out rather than using underlying CDC infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

Yugabyte team recently released a Debezium Connector for YugabyteDB at
https://github.com/yugabyte/debezium/releases

The document is at https://docs.yugabyte.com/preview/explore/change-data-capture/debezium-connector-yugabytedb/